# Practice Area for Posting

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I can't post as skillfully as I would like. The formatting help seems to be sufficient, but I would rather not play around with a live question comparing the look of one way of formatting to another.  Is there a way to play with formatting that won't be a nuisance?

> [SE team: could we have LaTeX and pretty printing enabled in this Meta for this purpose or would that be too demanding on the system? - Sjoerd]

Comment: Following R.M's suggestion, and because LaTeX support is present here that is not on the StackOverflow Meta, I have converted this entire thread to "community wiki" status so that it may itself be used as a sandbox.

Comment: You mean, the "Practice Area for Posting" thread?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Unfortunately we have neither LaTeX nor syntax highlighting on meta AFAIK :-(

Comment: So, to be clear, is it okay for me/us to post experimental attempts in this thread (as answers)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) on the main StackOverflow Meta site that was created for this purpose.

And maybe you have found it already, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is the documentation to the markup syntax which can be used to format your post. Additionally, on [mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) you can use LaTeX by inserting the code in either `$a=b$` for an inline formula or `$$a=b$$` for a separated formula.

Comment: Why not convert this post to CW and make it an explicit sandbox? That way people needn't head over to [metase]

Comment: @R.M. - So Excellent

Comment: I couldn't find an answer box on the SO Meta. I have 101 rep there and the rep threshold is 10 because it's protected. Doesn't look ideal for our needs.

Comment: @Sjoerd You've never contributed to Meta.SO?  How did you get this job? ;^)

Comment: My point is my rep>10, so I should be able to post there, but couldn't find an answer box. Do you see it?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think the rules for protected posts were changed so that you need to have 10 rep earned on the site before you can post. The association bonus doesn't count.

Comment: RM is correct; one has to have earned 10 rep in addition to any association bonuses to post on protected posts.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Sandbox on Math meta:

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370/10651

However, it doesn't support syntax coloring.

Answer (score 0):

Nice, but ....

$W_0 \sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{z}{\lambda\,\pi\, W_{0}^2}\right)}=W_1\;\,\quad \ldots(1)$

Comment: You mean there is no LaTeX on meta?  **facepalm**

Comment: @Mr.Wizard unless you see something that I can't ...

Comment: @belisarius thats why I explicitly linked to mma.SE and not to meta in my edit to Mr.Wizards post ;-).

Answer (score 0):

For example:

cashflow/(1 + interestrate)